# Spearman correlation for large dataset

Tags: r

I have two datasets (DataA and DataB) and I want to find the Spearman correlation between genes and also pull out the gene names (stored in first column of dataset) in `R`. I am using `fread` from `read.table` to read the file and `cor.test` to find `Rho` and `p-value`.
The code works fine for a smaller data set of 10 obs, 10 variables. But, my actual data set is larger (DataA - 795 obj, 542 variables and DataB - 925 obs, 542 variables). 
When I try to run the code on my actual data, it is consuming a large amount of time (it has been 23 hrs since my code is running). Is there a way to optimize this code? Or is there a bug in the code?

```
library(data.table)
A.data <- fread("DataA.csv", header = TRUE, data.table = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
B.data <- fread("DataB.csv", header = TRUE, data.table = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

correlation.result <- data.frame()

## Computing Correlation

for (i in 1:nrow(A.data)) {
  for (j in 1:nrow(B.data)) {
       correln <- cor.test(as.numeric(A.data[i,2:ncol(A.data)]), as.numeric(B.data[j,2:ncol(B.data)]), method = "spearman", exact = FALSE)
       rho <- correln$estimate
       p.val <- correln$p.value
       Gene <- paste(A.data[i,1], B.data[j,1], sep="_", collapse=" ") # To pullout gene name pairwise
       comb.data <- data.frame(rho, p.val, Gene)
       correlation.result <- rbind(correlation.result,comb.data)
 } 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code looks fine, but `rbind` to progressively build and resize a data frame can be gluttonous in terms of memory and time, especially given the A-row x B-row times you are doing this operation, which is fine for very small datasets, but not often realistic for real-world data.

Instead, perhaps `cat` results to a text file, where results are written in tab-delimited columns. You can then read in that text file later on.

In addition to serializing or saving your results to text, which make them easier to work with in non-R contexts, you won't have to deal with R's memory allocation problems when running `rbind` repeatedly. You just write out the answer to a file and read it in later on, in one pass.

Another approach is to preallocate memory to a presized data frame, and then write to that allocated space.

You know the size of your inputs ahead of time, which makes this approach tenable. In this case, it looks like you are storing two floats and a string (`rho`, `p.val`, and `Gene`) and that you are going to store A-row x B-row number of them.

Here's one way you might go about this:

```
# create a presized data frame
Arows <- nrow(A.data)
Brows <- nrow(B.data)
correlation.result <- data.frame(t(matrix(c(0.0, 0.0, "foo"), nrow=3, ncol=Arows * Brows)), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
colnames(correlation.result) <- c("rho", "p.val", "Gene")

# assign values to that presized data frame 
Acols <- ncol(A.data)
Bcols <- ncol(B.data)
for (i in 1:Arows) {
  # get A data
  Ai <- as.numeric(A.data[i, 2:Acols])
  Aname <- A.data[i, 1]
  for (j in 1:Brows) {
    # calculate row offset in presized data frame
    ij <- (i - 1) * Brows + j
    # get B data
    Bj <- as.numeric(B.data[j, 2:Bcols])
    Bname <- B.data[j, 1]
    # run test
    correln <- cor.test(Ai, Bj, method = "spearman", exact = FALSE)
    rho <- correln$estimate
    p.val <- correln$p.value
    Gene <- paste(Aname, Bname, sep="_", collapse=" ")
    # assign value to row of result data frame
    correlation.result[ij,] <- c(rho, p.val, Gene)
  }
}
```

This avoids R needing to resize and recopy the data frame contents as they grow, which I suspect is the major reason it is taking so long to run.

Chapter or "Circle" 2 of Patrick Burns' book *The R Inferno* discusses the problems with growing objects with `rbind` and ways to handle it — you might find this a useful read. This book is a PDF download via your search engine of choice.

Comment: Is there a reason for the downvote(s)?

Comment: I think it is bad for a community when downvoting without any explanation. Please explain yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `corr.test()` from psych [package](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/psych/versions/1.8.4/topics/corr.test), e.g.

```
ct <- corr.test(t(A.data), t(B.data), method='spearman', adjust='none')
```

then `ct$p` and `ct$r` would give you (uncorrected) p-value and correlation matrices of size `795 x 925`. Note that `t()` is required to compare matrices row-wise.

That would be orders of magnitude faster than loop-based approach.